# Jekyll not serving site local

Tags: localhost, jekyll

Configuration: windows7, ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x64-mingw32]

I have created a new Jekyll site via the command Jekyll new sitename.

I then enter that directory and issue the command Jekyll serve.

I get the following notice:

```
$ jekyll serve
Configuration file: C:/Users/Raha/Desktop/test/_config.yml
    Source: C:/Users/Raha/Desktop/test
       Destination: C:/Users/Raha/Desktop/test/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
                    done in 0.783 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'C:/Users/Raha/Desktop/test'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

But when I open http://127.0.0.1:4000/ I get this error 
This site can’t be reached!
I don't know how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Try opening `http://localhost:4000/`

Comment: I changed the port and it's working. Thanks